# Is the phrase I am flattered inherently negative?

Tags: phrases

Is the phrase I am flattered inherently negative?

for example

A : you're my favorite

B: I am flattered

Comment: Why should it be?

Comment: It is equivalent to "thank you", which can be positive or negative depending on context and tone.

Answer (score 4):

No is the short answer.

Stating **"I am flattered"** is equivalent to stating (in far fewer words):

> "I acknowledge your compliment and while I am not commenting on whether or not I agree with your compliment, I am nevertheless pleased that you think that way."

It is possible for "I am flattered" to be stated sarcastically (in the same matter that *everything* in English can be stated sarcastically). Applying that meaning (like all sarcasm) would require a significant change in tone as well as an accompanying facial expression of disgust or surprise.  It would perhaps be stated in that manner when the compliment is completely self-evident or when the listener does not actually believe that it is a compliment. Again, I'd like to emphasize that this entire paragraph applies equally well to all sarcasm and not just "I am flattered."